# Iterate over range, and "one more"

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, boost-graph

In the algorithm I'm currently implementing, there is this line (where `u` is a vertex in a graph, and `Pred(u)` are all vertices having edges pointing at `u`):

```
for all s ∈ Pred(u) ∪ {u}
```

The `Pred(u)` part I translate into boost::graph code like this:

```
boost::graph_traits<Graph>::in_edge_iterator in_begin, in_end;
boost::tie(in_begin, in_end) = boost::in_edges(u, G);
for(boost::graph_traits<Graph>::in_edge_iterator i = in_begin; i != in_end; ++i) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

For now, I'm doing the `Do stuff` stuff outside of the loop for `u` explicitly, but I'd like to do it in the `for` loop. Is there some trick to create the iterators as if `u` was returned from `boost::in_edges`?

Comment: That's a union, not a u in the middle of `Pred(u) ∪ {u}` right?

Comment: @awoodland: Yes. The font isn't great on readability, I agree.

Comment: Might just be my eyes and this monitor...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the solution you are using is alright (as long as the `Do stuff` code is well factorized).

However, if you often face such issues, you can have a look at [Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/range/), a library for manipulating ranges of values instead of iterators. Here, you could use the [join function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/utilities/join.html) to obtain the union of your two ranges (the result of `boost::in_edges` and `u`).

Comment: +1, I didn't know about Boost.Range and it looks very useful.